# ¿Como ejecutar solo una funcion en jquery validate?

Tags: jquery-validate

tengo el siguiente formulario:

```
<form id="form_telefonoadicional">
            <div class="list-block no-hairlines">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <div class="item-content">
                            <div class="item-inner">
                                <div class="item-title label">Número de teléfono</div>
                                <div class="item-input">
                                    <input type="text" name="telefono" id="telefono" required />
                                </div>
                                <div class="item-text input-error"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="align-top">
                        <div class="item-content">
                            <div class="item-inner">
                                <div class="item-title label">Correo Electronico</div>
                                <div class="item-input">
                                    <input type="text" name="correo" id="correo" required />
                                </div>
                                <div class="item-text input-error"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="content-block">
                <div class="row">
                    <span class="col-50 button-icon-ant" data-icon="&#xf053;">
                        <button class="regresarProforma">Anterior</button>
                    </span>
                    <span class="col-50 button-icon" data-icon="&#xf054;">
                        <button type="submit" id="formasPagos" class="">Siguiente</button>
                    </span> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Dentro el formulario tengo 2 botones de Anterior y siguiente:
El inconveniente que tengo es de que al dar click en el boton anterior, debe regresar a la vista anterior sin validar el formulario y al darle en siguiente si debe validar el formulario para continuar a la siguiente vista.
Las funciones las tengo de esta forma:

```
$('#form_telefonoadicional').validate({
        rules:{
            telefono:{
                required: true
            }
        },
         messages:{
            telefono:{
                required: "Este campo es requerido"
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form,e){
            console.log("formulario validado");
            mainView.router.load({
                url: 'vistas/formaspagos.html'
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });


    $$(".regresarProforma").on('click', function (e) {
        mainView.router.load({
            url: 'vistas/proforma.html'
        });
    });
```

El detalle surge cuando ya valida el formulario, ingresa al submitHandler pero no envía a la ruta `vistas/formaspagos.html`, si no que lo envía a `vistas/proforma.html`, es como si primero ejecutara el botón Anterior. 
Como podría corregir esto.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es por el tipo del boton:

```
 <button type="submit">
```

Quita el type="submit" y dejalo como button sino al hacer click el comportamiento del tipo submit es enviar el formulario y por ende se ejecuta el validate.

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias, me ha funcionado al momento de darle click al boton siguiente, pero cuando he terminado de llenar los campos y presiono enter, ejecuta primero la funcion del boton "Anterior"

Comment: coloca <button type="button" a Anterior, ya que sino colocas nada es como decir que es <button type="submit">.

Comment: Muchas gracias.